# Get Bluetooth input in Phonegap

Tags: android, ios, cordova, bluetooth

I am trying to interface with a bluetooth barcode scanner in my phonegapo application, In android and IOS, android being the priority at the moment. I am planning on using this plugin: 
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Bluetooth

I am not opposed to switching plugins or even writing my own though. Having looked through the code for this plugin I do not see anything like an event that the scanner would generate. Maybe I'm missing something? Thanks, I am fairly new to android development and phonegap.

Also, if anyone has any input on where to start with IOS that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Using a bluetooth barcode scanner in combination with cordova should not be a problem. I ve tested the same scenario with a KDC scanner on Android 4.x

The easiest solution is to setup the scanner as HID Keyboard. Then change the settings in Android not to use a physical Keyboard ( Juat to keep the on screen keyboard ).

Inside your application just add a listener to body for keyUp/Down events.

Asap the scanner sends a barcode ( sequence of chars ) the attached listener will get invoked.

To seperate a call from you scanner from a regular input, configure your barcode scanner to use a suffix and a prefix, which will never occur as regular input like $#++ as prefix and ++#$ as suffix.

Inside your listener just keep track of the input. If the prefix pattern occurs start recording all chars until the suffix pattern occurs.

Hope this helps

Regards